# Create a CASE in WHERE which depends on a parameter

Tags: t-sql

```
DECLARE @MyParam bit = 1

SELECT * FROM MyTable mt

WHERE
   CASE WHEN @MyParam = 1 THEN mt.MyFK IS NULL
   CASE WHEN @MyParam = 0 THEN mt.MyFK IS NOT NULL
   END
```

How to write a query to filter where MyFK is null if my parameter is 1? It works with sipmle CASE and number

```
WHERE mt.MyFK = (CASE WHEN @MyParam = 1 THEN 1)
```

but not with 'IS NULL'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable mt

WHERE
   ( @MyParam = 1 AND mt.MyFK IS NULL )
 OR
   ( @MyParam = 0 AND mt.MyFK IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: No need for case ... thanks.